# initialize Bootstrap Material Design in Ember.js App

Tags: javascript, ember.js, material-design, ember-cli, bootstrap-material-design

I started learning Ember.js one week ago and I'm trying to integrate the [Bootstrap Material Design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/#getting-started) in my app. I have read the documentation that says I need to call:

```
$.material.init()
```

I have tried to create a instance initializer and put this code in, but nothing happened.

Can anyone help me out to initialize the material effects in my Ember app?

Comment: For one thing, you can directly put that in a script tag in your index.hmtl file

Comment: Thanks @ManishKr.Shukla, but this is not Ember way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. According to the Ember Documentation, we can use an [Application Instance Initializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/applications/initializers/) which can run code when our App is loaded.

> Application instance initializers are run as an application instance is loaded. They provide a way to configure the initial state of your application, as well as to set up dependency injections that are local to the application instance (e.g. A/B testing confurations).

So, I just generated a new instance initializer using ember-cli

```sh
ember generate instance-initializer bootstrap-material
```

And called the [Bootstrap Material Design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) JS function:

```js
// app/instance-initializers/bootstrap-material.js
import Ember from 'ember'

export function initialize(applicationInstance) {
    Ember.$.material.init();
};

export default {
    name: 'bootstrap-material',
    initialize: initialize
};
```

That is all I have done to get it working. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did exactly the same, but it's sadly not working (using Ember 2.3). `Ember.$.material` is available but `init()`-call does nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Did `Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', this, function () { Ember.$.material.init(); }` inside `setupController()` of my ApplicationController, which works for me.

Comment: It might have changed in ember 2.3. I am using ember 2.0. Have you seen the docs?

Comment: I've debugged into it and the problem was that `material.init()` get's called before anything rendered (so instance-initializer might called too early) and the `init()` had no effect.

Comment: I keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` whenever I use the initializer you provided above. I installed the package with npm is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: @Sean I really don't know what is happening. could you show me your code? are you using ember 2.0 or 2.3?

Comment: @BrunoPaulino I am using Ember 2.3. The code I have is exactly the same as the initializer above. Did you install with Bower or NPM? I basically have the opposite problem as the first comment where `material` does not appear to be available on the jQuery object

Comment: That is great @Sean. Could you show how did you get it running?

Comment: @BrunoPaulino I put `Ember.$.material.init()` in the `setupController` hook in the application route, imported the material and ripple JS files in the ember-cli-build file, remove the `importBootsrapTheme` from ember-cli-build file that I originally added from the ember-bootstrap addon, and finally import the material and ripple CSS files in my `app.scss` file

Answer (score 0):

My solution with Ember 2.12.01 was wrapping the `$.material.init();` in a function

```
var initMD = function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.material.init();
    })
}
```

and in my router call this function using the [`didTransition`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition) action

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        didTransition() {
            initTheme();
            return true; // Bubble the didTransition event
        }
    },
    [...]
}
```